# How to access AWS secrets manager secrets in Kubernetes config map

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-secrets-manager

I have secrets stored in AWS secrets manager in the below format.

the secret name is /app/dev/ and it has all the secrets in it as keys and values
like

```
 Key     Value
value1   XYZ
Value2   ABC
```

How do I access these secrets in config map

Here's my config map

```
apiversion:v1
data:
vaule1: **secret from AWS secrets manager
Vaule2: **secret from AWS secrets manager
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make available secrets manager secrets as environmental variables in aws eks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247203/how-to-make-available-secrets-manager-secrets-as-environmental-variables-in-aws)

Comment: Can you also helo with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76519876/how-to-mount-each-aws-secrets-as-separate-volume-in-eks @ChinHuang